# Adding Sticker Pack to existing iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, imessage

How do I add a sticker pack extension to an existing app? I want the user to install my app, then have access to the sticker pack as a bonus.

I've tried:

1. Adding a sticker pack extension target to my project, when I build
   that target it opens in iMessage and functions as desired, however
   when I build the main target and open iMessage it doesn't show my
   sticker pack (I've checked the iMessage menu to make sure it wasn't
   just disabled)
2. Added a sticker pack asset file to my project, does nothing
3. Added a sticker pack icon file and sticker pack to my asset file,
   does nothing

Answer (score 5):

Stickerpacks can be added to your Project. Add `"Sticker Pack Extention"` as Extention type and make sure the `Wrapper Extention` is set to .appex

You'll probably want to use the parent Bundle ID. If you already have a live app, create a Wildcard App ID

- Parent: com.domain.apps.myapp (Create a Wildcard App ID and appropriate provisioning profiles)
- Child: com.domain.apps.myapp.stickers